# Cannot run Django development server (UnicodeDecodeError)

Tags: python, django, unicode, python-unicode

When I am trying to run django development server (using command line or pycharm Run feature) I get following error traceback:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x037EF170>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 222, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 159, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 173, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 95, in load_disk
    if name.endswith(".py"):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix that?

Edit:
I've checked how it works when I delete all migrations and re-create them. When I do so, server is starting without any issue. HOWEVER, when I've switched to another machine and tried to start server (I am syncing files via dropbox) error message appears again.

Comment: This may come from a the fact that youŕe using `Python2.7` with a version of Django that is not compatible with it - or so I remember reading something similar in the docs. Or it could be that some files or paths contains unusual characters

Comment: Indeed, my migrations contain special characters, like: "Okres wa\u017cno\u015bci pakietu" but I am not sure it it is the reason of the issue

Comment: Handling this goes beyond my knowledge of Django but you could look in the documentation to this how this could be handled or more simply replace those special characters.

Comment: I use Dropbox and I just had the same issue. Actually there were some *.pyc files in migrations directory with comments about conflicts during sync. I had been getting this error because of the cyrillic symbols in those files names. Maybe it will be helpful for some folks.

Answer (score 1):

I met the similar problem when I ran `python managy.py runserver` with Django 1.10.

My system is: win10.
Python version: 2.7.13 (in Anacoda)

The error traceback is below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2sUN.jpg)

I got the answer from Django project troubleshooting

> Your system locale may be a default ASCII locale, like the “C” locale on UNIX-like systems (can be checked by the locale command). If it’s the case, please refer to your system documentation to learn how you can change this to a UTF-8 locale.

So in Windows 10 I changed system locale from Chinese to English refer to this question --- [How to change system locale in Windows 10 - The Language for - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfbook-surfaccess/how-to-change-system-locale-in-windows-10-the/d7826ef0-13cd-43ea-8e01-2846d813dfed).

Then I rebooted my computer, and it's OK to run `python managy.py runserver` again.

May it will help someone.

Comment: Here is the Django troubleshooting: [Troubleshooting | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/faq/troubleshooting/#i-m-getting-a-unicodedecodeerror-what-am-i-doing-wrong)